# Firebase app works only on localhost, init and deploy was successfull

Tags: firebase

my firebase app only shows the app on localhost. I initialized and deployed the app successfully and when and want to show it here https://techmatrixzeiterfassung.firebaseapp.com/ it does only show a blank page. I already replaced the index.html which firebase replaces through the original one

This is my firebase.json file

```
    {
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some more information? Seems like it should have worked.

Answer (score 0):

When I open dev tools in Chrome, I can see your code.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png">
    <!--
      Notice the use of %PUBLIC_URL% in the tag above.
      It will be replaced with the URL of the `public` folder during the build.
      Only files inside the `public` folder can be referenced from the HTML.
      Unlike "/favicon.ico" or "favicon.ico", "%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" will
      work correctly both with client-side routing and a non-root public URL.
      Learn how to configure a non-root public URL by running `npm run build`.
    -->
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    <title>Techmatrix Zeiterfassung</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <!-- This script adds the Roboto font to our project. For more detail go to this site:  http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Roboto:400,300,500 -->
    <script>
      var WebFontConfig = {
        google: { families: [ 'Roboto:400,300,500:latin' ] }
      };
      (function() {
        var wf = document.createElement('script');
        wf.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https' : 'http') +
        '://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1/webfont.js';
        wf.type = 'text/javascript';
        wf.async = 'true';
        var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(wf, s);
      })();
    </script>

    <div id="root"></div>
    <!--
      This HTML file is a template.
      If you open it directly in the browser, you will see an empty page.
      You can add webfonts, meta tags, or analytics to this file.
      The build step will place the bundled scripts into the <body> tag.
      To begin the development, run `npm start`.
      To create a production bundle, use `npm run build`.
    -->
  </body>
</html>
```

There isn't actually any HTML in the index that would display on the browser. I added a div from dev tools and it showed up as expected

There is an error that displays in the console:

> /%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.png:1 Failed to load resource: the server
>   responded with a status of 400 ()

Perhaps you were expecting to see an icon on the screen?